# What is best way to add product features in django with database mysql

Tags: mysql, django, database, django-models

I want to store product features in MySQL database so, I've some confusion about which way is better to store it for better performance as well as for scalability.

Basically as per my idea, I design models like given below: in that, I have a product table, features table which contains field product type for which type of product belongs to this particular feature. the last table is product_features in that I actually storing data of specific product_id and feature_id is it the right way?

I'm using Django. so here's is my model!

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null = False, unique=True)
    product_slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null = True)
    product_info = models.TextField(null = False)
    product_description = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    product_price = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(Product_type, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    product_status = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default = "publish")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

class Feature(models.Model):
    feature_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    feature_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null = False)
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(Product_type, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    feature_has_value = models.CharField(max_length = 1, null = False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

class Product_feature(models.Model):
    product_feature_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    feature = models.ForeignKey(Feature, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    product_feature_value = models.CharField(max_length=255, null = False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
```

Comment: Is the same feature used for multiple products? Are you going to update this feature and it equally applies to all products?

Comment: @danblack actually i've 1 other model called product type in that i have some type like accounting software, School Management Software, etc. so every product type have their features and in product table i've that product type linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my thought your model is looks good for the product feature except primary key field in all model, no need to manage `primary key` in django model because django already manage `id` field as `primary key` for each model.

Second thing is generally many time there will be discounts on particular product in online shopping site so, if your plan is also something like that then you can also add one discount model in your app.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and you think it's not good to use id field explicitly right? but I think Django gives field named the only id so it's little bit confusing when deal with multiple tables

Comment: As per you is it a good approach or it'll create a problem in the future?

Comment: No it will not create any problem in future because if you want to use `id` of any object then you can directly use `model_object.id`. So, it will not create any type of confusion to identify the `id` because it will identify by its `model_object` variable too.

Comment: Yup! Thanks for help @MK Patel

Comment: Always... Happy Coding :)